# A reasonable way to design this dynamoDB schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I currently have the following data in my DynamoDB table:

```
person_id_and_gender | ttl(timestamp) | person_movie_rate                                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_1:male            | 123456789      | amazing_spider_man:0.8, iron_man:0.674, dr_strange:0.32, ...  |
id_9:non-binary      | 123000089      | batman:0.9, iron_man:0.874, terminator:0.55, lala_land:0.5 ...|
...
```

As you can see, this table is trying to save the relationship between a person and his/her/their ratings to a list of different movies. As the number of new movies increases rapidly, the entry size limit (400k) has been hit and thus we must cut off some ratings in order to fit into one entry of a person.

**Current config**: `person_id_and_gender` is the primary key of this table and it does not have a sort key.

Is there a better way to re-design this schema so the we won't explode the entry even if we have more and more ratings?

Please note:

1. All column names/attributes are made up. They only serve as examples (Maybe bad examples though).
2. In our use case, we might have more "genders" (male, female, non-binary and more...)
3. In our use case, we assume one person may have different genders, in other words, we may see `id_2:male` and `id_2:female` shows up in the same table, and we need both data points.

**Update**:
The current query pattern is just getting a list of movie ratings by `person_id_and_gender`, in other words, all ratings of a single person.

Comment: One way I can think of: The `person_movie_rate` object can be stored in a separate S3 bucket and the link to that object can be stored in the dynamo db.

Comment: Whenever you design a NoSQL schema, you need to be aware of the access patterns you want to serve - what are those?

Comment: @AmeyaS Thanks, and that is what I tried: I saved the list of ratings as csv file and uploaded it to s3, but it results the uploading job timing out too often. It took me like 30 minutes to upload the data using 32 threads.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks I have updated the question. And I will do so for future NoSQL questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the usual health warning about [starting with access patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach) applies. With that big caveat in mind, a pattern that scales with the number of ratings would be:

| PK | SK | rating | birthday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `id_1:male` | `Attributes` |  | `2000-01-10` |
| `id_1:male` | `Rating#amazing_spider_man` | `0.8` |  |
| `id_1:male` | `Rating#iron_man` | `0.674` |  |
| `id_9:non-binary` | `Rating#iron_man` | `0.874` |  |

This uses generic key names (`PK` and `SK`) and compound sort key values to model [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html) in a [single table design](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/).

```sh
PK = "id_1:male" AND SK = "Attributes" # user attributes
PK = "id_1:male" AND SK > "Rating" # all ratings for a user
PK = "id_1:male" AND SK = "Rating#amazing_spider_man" # user rating for a specific movie
```

If your use case requires querying by movie, you can add an [index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) where the keys are swapped: `GSI1PK` is the movie and `GSI1SK` is the user_id.

Furthermore, if you invert the gender and id in the index's SK, you can query movie rating by gender.

```sh
GSI1PK = "iron_man" AND GSI1SK > "" # iron man ratings for all users
GSI1PK = "iron_man" AND begins_with(GSISK, "non-binary") #  iron man ratings for non-binary users
```

Comment: I want to update that we ended up uploading the data to s3 and use the s3 key (directory path) as the "primary key" to fetch data because the data size was too big -- for one id there can be up to 111,000 ratings, storing it in ddb may end up with many duplicates (ex. the `id:gender`).

Answer (score 1):

You don’t specify your query and update patterns so it’s hard to give a definitive answer.

Guessing at your patterns, my suggestion would be make the movie title the sort key. You could then get_item a person’s rating for a movie or query to fetch all a person’s (gender-tied) ratings. No movie count limit. You can keep the TTL on each item if you’d like.